# angular 2 - child component canDeactivate without routes

Tags: angular, routes, navigation

I have written a component which is simple fields and I am using a child component which is not a form but to add some fields on parent component object. I have implemented canDeactivate which is working perfectly but not for child component.

```
<factory-relationship [relationships]="model.relationships" (relationshipUpdated)="relationshipUpdated($event)"></factory-relationship>
```

my route is below for parent:

```
{ path: 'factory', component: FactoryFormComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard] },
{ path: 'factory/:id', component: FactoryFormComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard] },
```

as for factory-relationship, I just import it and use it. which adds relationship in an array and I update parent component's model to add relationships. Below is screenshot of the page. I am not sure how to show discard Changes when I add relationships and navigate away.

As you can see from screenshot I have added relationship but when i navigate away, it doesnt show discard changes. Not sure how can i apply canDeactivate without routes.

> factory-relationship.component.ts (omitted some code)

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'factory-relationship',
    templateUrl: 'factory-relationship.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['../shared/app.shared.css']
})
export class FactoryRelationshipComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() relationshipUpdated = new EventEmitter();
    @Input() relationships: Array<Relationship>;
    private relationshipForm: FormGroup;
    private showValidation: boolean = false;

    private errorMessage: string;
    private suppliers: Supplier[];
    private businessAreas: BusinessArea[];
    private contacts: Contact[];
    private active: boolean = true;

    relationshipCols: any[];

    constructor(private supplierService: SupplierService, private businessAreaService: BusinessAreaService,
        private router: Router, private utilityService: UtilityService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
        this.relationshipCols = [
            { field: 'supplierName', header: 'supplierName' },
            { field: 'businessArea', header: 'businessArea' },
            { field: 'supplierId', header: 'supplierId' },
            { field: 'businessAreaId', header: 'businessAreaId' }
        ];
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getSuppliers();
        this.getBusinessArea();

        this.relationshipForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            selectedSupplier: ['', [<any>Validators.required]],
            selectedBusinessArea: ['', [<any>Validators.required]],
            selectedContact: ['', [<any>Validators.required]]
        });

        this.relationshipForm.controls.selectedBusinessArea.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
            if(value !== null)
                this.getContactsForBusinessArea(value)
        });
    }

    private resetForm(): void {
        this.relationshipForm.reset();
        this.relationships.filter(relationship => relationship.inEditMode === true).forEach(x=>x.inEditMode = false);
    }

    private isEditMode(): boolean {
        return (this.relationships.filter(relationship => relationship.inEditMode === true)).length > 0;
    }

    private onSubmit(): void {
        if (this.relationshipForm.valid) {
            let editableRelationship = this.relationships.find(relationship => relationship.inEditMode === true);

            if (editableRelationship) {
                this.createRelationship(editableRelationship);
                editableRelationship.inEditMode = false;
            } else
                this.relationships.push(this.createRelationship(null));

            this.relationshipUpdated.emit(this.relationships);
            this.showValidation = false;
            this.relationshipForm.reset();
        }
        else {
            this.showValidation = true;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you solved that? You can find that `interface CanDeactivate<T> { 
  canDeactivate(component: T` is a generic function - so that makes me thing that we must create different classes for every component..?

Comment: @J.D. I was never able to solve this and didn't pursue this further. I show/hide child component for alternate solution.

Comment: From what I understand, because its a generic function, every component type must have his own `CanDeactivateGuard`

Comment: @J.D. could be...I am not sure why we would have to implement for every single component. its very tedious.